# Typescript difference between T and "T extends unknown"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In typescipt, what is the difference between between `T` and `T extends unknown` when used as type parameter. For example:

```
function check<T extends unknown>(x: T): T {
    return x;
}
```

vs

```
function check<T>(x: T): T {
    return x;
}
```

Is there any difference between them in terms of behaviour?

Comment: there's no difference, `T extends unknown` resolves to `T`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe these are more or less equivalent:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type

> `unknown` is the type-safe counterpart of any. Anything is assignable to `unknown`, but `unknown` isn’t assignable to anything but itself and `any` without a type assertion or a control flow based narrowing. Likewise, no operations are permitted on an `unknown` without first asserting or narrowing to a more specific type.

Comment: Yes. I was on this link a while earlier, and yes they feel equivalent to me as well. But I see "T extends unknown" used extensively in a codebase that I need to work with. Unfortunately the author is not accessible. So I thought I will ask here to be absolutely sure about it.